# Private property in coreData entity

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Is it possible using private property in coreData entity.

I need to create a var with just Get return that return a enum based in private NSNumber property.

Leave this property public works fine, but I want to prevent external classes change NSNumber value

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Now that the CoreData Entity properties are stored in an extension. It is very easy to add and maintain your own custom logic and properties/data in the main entity class file.

Comment: Thanks by answer me. Do you have some example how using a property in extesion and apply a private property. I know xcode just re-genarate just extension class. I don't know how to do this in imutable class