# Private attributes/properties and Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data

I am attempting to transform one of my model objects into a Core Data managed Entity, the object has a private list of sub-objects.

I don't want users of the object to be able to access the list, but instead create, update and calculate values using the business logic in the object, something akin to:

```swift
struct MyObject {
    private let listOStuff: [String]

    func updateBusinessLogic(value: String): MyObject {
        // business logic here
        return ... // new version of MyObject 
    }
}
```

I understand I can use an extension to add the required business logic to the managed object; but is Core Data able to handle the property/attribute being private?

Thanks

PS [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38082754/4187837) is the closest answer I can see to my problem, but I don't think it is the same.